# Heroku error: The scope body needs to be callable (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, scope

I get this error when I deploy to Heroku. The app is deployed but I have an Application Error message when I open the app on my browser.

I don't really understand why I got this error. Looked up my scopes and everything's fine. There's no syntax or anything...

Heroku logs:

```
    2017-12-21T16:20:44.520142+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2017-12-21T16:20:45.022771+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/scoping/named.rb:143:in `scope': The scope body needs to be callable. (ArgumentError)
2017-12-21T16:20:45.022814+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rich-1.4.6/app/models/rich/rich_file.rb:10:in `<class:RichFile>'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.022827+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rich-1.4.6/app/models/rich/rich_file.rb:6:in `<module:Rich>'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.022840+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rich-1.4.6/app/models/rich/rich_file.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.022853+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.022890+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.022905+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.022917+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.022930+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:360:in `require_or_load'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.022942+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:317:in `depend_on'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.022955+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:233:in `require_dependency'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.022967+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:472:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.022979+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `each'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.022992+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `block in eager_load!'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.023004+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `each'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.023016+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `eager_load!'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.023043+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:346:in `eager_load!'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.023109+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.023123+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.023136+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.023148+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.023160+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.023172+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.023185+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.023209+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.023237+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.023254+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.023269+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.023285+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.023300+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.023316+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.023331+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.023345+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.023359+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.023382+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.023404+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.023418+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.023506+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.023754+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.023771+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.023789+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.023807+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.023823+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.023839+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.023853+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.023868+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.023913+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/server.rb:300:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.023931+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/server.rb:209:in `app'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.023948+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.023968+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/server.rb:337:in `wrapped_app'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.023985+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/server.rb:273:in `start'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.024002+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.024171+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.024188+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.024204+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.024338+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.024321+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.024354+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:9:in `require'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.024369+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
2017-12-21T16:20:45.233312+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-12-21T16:20:45.218712+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-12-21T16:20:51.964132+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=afternoon-beyond-98583.herokuapp.com request_id=fe3ee2ae-c79f-4636-b07b-81484e12300e fwd="37.172.154.21" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-12-21T16:20:46.783888+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=afternoon-beyond-98583.herokuapp.com request_id=ea904370-1b61-4cb5-854a-056b0b46cf37 fwd="37.172.154.21" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Scopes model:

```
scope :normal, lambda { where(produit_type: 'normal') }

scope :abonnements, lambda { where(produit_type: 'abonnement') }

scope :box, lambda { where(produit_type: 'box') }
```

Comment: Are you using the `rich` gem (https://github.com/kreativgebiet/rich/releases)? It looks like you're using Rails 4 so you may want to upgrade the rich gem.

Comment: The scopes looked fine to you, but evidently, there's a problem. Under those circumstances, would it not be prudent to post any code where you're defining scopes in case someone else can see something you didn't?

Comment: @DerekHopper I upgraded the rich gem but nothing happens. Just edited my post by adding scopes